# Cannot display Tiny MCE Editor inside update panel C#

Tags: c#, javascript

I cannot display my tiny MCE editor inside update panel.

I have two update panel using update mode `"conditional"`
In the first I added button on click of it display MCE editor which is inside second update panel
I did this from my code behind, `on click` event I updated both panels

```
UpdatePanel1.Update();
UpdatePanel2.Update();

div.Style.Add("display", "block");//this is inside second update pane
```

Its simple text Area rather than MCE editor itself..

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the initializing method of the TinyMCE whenever the update panel is refreshed.

For this, you have either to call this method (tinyMCE.init) from a RegisterStartupScript method,

```
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
      {                
          ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, 
              this.Page.GetType(), mce.ClientID, "callInt" + mce.ClientID + "();",  true);
       }
```

**OR** to create a page load javascript function in the head section of the page like this:

```
     function pageLoad() 
     {
         tinyMCE.init();
      }


      <body onload="pageLoad()">  
      </body>
```

Hope this helps..